# How to calculate joint feature contribution for XGBoost Classifier in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, xgboost, shap

I referred to http://savvastjortjoglou.com/intrepretable-machine-learning-nfl-combine.html#Joint-Feature-Contributions this beautiful document to research about joint feature contibutions. But this works only for RandomForest algorithms because of treeinterpreter (does not work with xgboost). Is there a similar way out for XGBoost as well?

Basically what I want to achieve is to find out the joint contributions of all the combination of features towards the prediction. For example if I have a, b and c as my features, I want to know what is the effect of ab, bc and ca towards the prediction result. It is very similar to shap and lime but for combination of features.

Comment: have you tried with the scikit learn api ? https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

Comment: You can ask your question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
As a quick answer, not all machine learning algorithms support what you're looking for...

Comment: I have checked out the documentation but did not find anything there.

Comment: I did post the same question on datascience,stackexchange.com. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @SudhakarSamak sorry I can't help, but I am interested in if/when you find a valid solution to this. Please keep us posted

Comment: @chitown88 See if this helps

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give this a look after.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and learnt about xgbfir package. It spits joint contributions into an excel file. You can set the level of interaction with this. I wrote some code around it to generate a plot that solves the purpose.

If the package is not installed

```
pip install xgbfir
```

After the installation:

```
import xgbfir
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xgbfir.saveXgbFI(model, feature_names=X.columns, OutputXlsxFile='FI.xlsx')

joint_contrib = pd.read_excel('FI.xlsx')

xls = pd.ExcelFile('FI.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Interaction Depth 0')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Interaction Depth 1')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Interaction Depth 2')

frames = [df1, df2, df3]
joint_contrib = pd.concat(frames)

joint_contrib=joint_contrib.sort_values(by='Gain', ascending=True)
joint_contrib=joint_contrib.head(20)

height = joint_contrib['Gain']
bars = joint_contrib['Interaction']
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

plt.barh(y_pos, height)
plt.yticks(y_pos, bars)
plt.show()
```

This will give the top 20 feature interactions in terms of gain.

Thanks to Philip Cho who introduced me to xgbfir.

Follow the link for more information regarding [xgbfir](https://github.com/limexp/xgbfir)